MoviePy SubtitlesClip will not accept any provided font (Python)
I am currently trying out moviepy to burn subtitles on a video. However I keep getting the same error message no matter what I do. This is the code I am using:
from moviepy import TextClip
from moviepy.video.tools.subtitles import SubtitlesClip
...
generator = lambda txt: TextClip(
    text = self.txt,
    font = self.font_path,
    font_size = 100,
    color= self.text_color,
    stroke_color="black",
    stroke_width=5,
)
subtitles = SubtitlesClip(self.subtitles_path, generator)

where self.font_path is currently the string "/fonts/my_font.otf". Regardless of the font however, I keep getting the error message:
ValueError: Invalid font <function _spyderpdb_code.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x7b89f4d60e00>, pillow failed to use it with error 'function' object has no attribute 'read'


[mre] required. ... suggests something's missing, variables such as self.txt are undefined.

The documented example for that functionality seems to be wrong.
You'd probably need
subtitles = SubtitlesClip(self.subtitles_path, make_textclip=generator)

i.e. pass your generator as make_textclip, not as the positional font argument.
(I created a PR to fix the example. https://github.com/Zulko/moviepy/pull/2271)
